# vue-filter doesn't work with v-html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

This problem has few solutions but nothing worked for me. I am using a package called `vue-filter` and I want to use `nl2br` filter. When I try to use it in my html like this

```
<p style="padding: 10px;font-size: 17px;"  v-html="$options.filters.nl2br(opDesc.description)"></p>
```

It gives me the following error

```
TypeError: _vm.$options.filters.nl2br is not a function
```

Here is the package github link https://github.com/wy-ei/vue-filter#nl2br

Comment: See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4352#issuecomment-283324408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ok. Filters does not works in v-html directive. Only in mustache interpolations and v-bind directive.

Use computed property instead:

```
<any-tag v-html="filtered" />
```

In component, use something like this:

```
computed: {
  filtered () {
    return this.nl2br(this.rawHtml)
  }
},
methods: {
  nl2br (source) {
    var filtered = //Filter logic here
    return filtered
  }
}
```

Comment: Any solution you can suggest?

Comment: @sadek Solution added to answer.

Comment: See  better approach at https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4352#issuecomment-283324408

Answer (score 4):

You can use

- `v-html="$options.filters.FILTERNAME(args)"` or
- `:inner-html.prop="args | FILTERNAME"`.

See demo below.

```js
Vue.filter('upper', function (value) {
    return value.toUpperCase();
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-html="$options.filters.upper(message)"></p>
  
  <p :inner-html.prop="message | upper"></p>
</div>
```